# Why not drawn the second circle?

Tags: javascript, canvas, onclick

I want to by clicking on the mouse button to draw circles. Why not drawn the second circle? I have Chrome 39.0.2171.99 m. On the latest version of firefox I checked also.

```js
var mx = document.getElementById("mx");
var my = document.getElementById("my");
var can = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var canLeft = can.offsetLeft, canTop = can.offsetTop;
var g = can.getContext('2d');

// Draw circle with text
function drawCircleWithText(g, x, y, r, text, bgclr, textclr) {
 g.fillStyle = bgclr || "black";
 g.beginPath();
 g.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
 g.closePath();
 g.fill();
 g.fillStyle = textclr || "white";
 g.font = "bold "+r+"px serif";
 var w = g.measureText(text).width,
  h = g.measureText("w").width;
 g.fillText(text, x - w/2, y + h/2);
 //console.log("End DCWT: ",x,y,r,text);
}

var r = 20, n = 0;

// Add event listener for `click` events.
can.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var x = event.pageX - canLeft,
        y = event.pageY - canTop;

    drawCircleWithText(g, x, y, r, ""+(++n));

}, false);

can.onmousemove = function(e) {
    mx.innerHTML =  e.x;
    my.innerHTML = e.y;
}
```

```html
<span id="mx">0</span>, <span id="my">0</span><br>
<canvas id="mainCanvas" width="300" 
height="400" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

**Excuse Me. The problem with the computer.**

Comment: It works in Chrome 39

Comment: Works on latest Firefox (v35) too.

Comment: I guess I have a problem with your computer.

Comment: Is there an array of circles that you have to iterate over?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your problem, this is working fine for me.
May be your problem is not clear to me, or may be you are writing canvas tag after script tag inside body tag.